# Extract subnet id's based on subnet name in virgina region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, subnet

I need to extract the subnet ids by passing the subnet names and get the output of the subnet ids.

main.tf

```
module "data" {
    source      =   "./data"

}

output "subnetid" {
  description = "The current bid status of the Spot Instance Request"
  value       = module.data.subnetid
}
```

Module data folder.

data.tf

```
data "aws_vpc" "vpc-id" {
  filter {
    name   = "tag:Name"
    values = ["kdt-vpc"]
  }

}

data "aws_subnets" "selected" {
  filter {
    name   = "vpc-id"
    values = [data.aws_vpc.vpc-id.id]
  }
  filter {
    name   = "tag:Name"
    values = ["kdt-private-subnet-0","kdt-private-subnet-1"] # insert values here
  }
}
```

outputs.tf

```
output "subnetid" {
  description = "The current bid status of the Spot Instance Request"
  value       = data.aws_subnets.selected.id
}
```

When I run the terraform apply I am getting the output as

Changes to Outputs:

- subnetid = "us-east-1"

How Can I get the correct subnet id's by passing the two subnet names

Comment: hi Mark , Can you help me on this

Comment: What could be done - 

1. Take the subnet IDs and pass it to data aws_subnet block.
2. From aws_subnet, you can get the AZ details as well

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/subnet